# Accessing html elements in an Umbraco view file from model file

Tags: umbraco

I am working on a personal umbraco project integrating a third party code into my umbraco website. I have two div containers in a view (BVSummaryContainer & BVRRContainer). I have the code in the attached image in a model file and it comes up with a build error. How can I modify the code in the image to remove the build error and access the innerHtml of both Dovs. Thanks.[model file code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjijo.jpg)

Comment: I assume that you are using Umbraco 7.* and asp.net MVC?

Comment: Yes but the code I was given from the third party vendor is in an an aspx .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Umbraco question.

You can use try catch block for avoiding crashes.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand by "It's not related to Umbraco question"